# call function inside web view after source is loaded

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xamarin.android, youtube

I use a webview to display embeded youtube videos

```
WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0";
settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

webview.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/youTube.html");
```

The html file is a simple one that have the javascript function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function callJS() {
            video = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0];
            alert(video.currentTime);
        }
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width=" 200" height=" 400" src=" strUrl"> </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

For simplicity I replaced the function to alert("demo");

When a button clicked is subscribe to the event to call the function

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(MessengerKeys.App, MessengerKeys.Position,
    (s) =>
        {
            if (webview != null)
            {
                webview.LoadUrl("javascript:callJS();");
            }
        }
);
```

The function is called successfully but after load the embeded video the function never called

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

I am nearly certain that the problem has to do with your event being called too soon on android side.
See, when your WebView is initialized, and when your app is ready to take events are two different things.

Possible solution would be to first send a appReady event from JS to Android.

Then run your callJS event.

Comment: No, i don't think so. callJS event is fired successfully but if i changed the src  url to the embeded video it's not fired